# Purpose of /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/

Tags: wireless, cloud

I recently had trouble to have a working WiFi on my Raspberry Pi 4 (Ubuntu 20.04). I found this tutorial online which help me solving the issue.

The trick is to create a file in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/ named 99-disable-network-config.cfg.

The content of the file is just this line :

```
network: {config: disabled}
```

While this works on my RPi4, I do not understand what is the purpose of such a file in this specific folder. Additionally, I do not understand the line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me tell you from my perspective.
On my system, in `/etc/netplan` there is a file with the name `50-cloud-init.yaml`

The comment block in it goes like:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
```

I guess, creating `99-disable-network-config.cfg` makes a process read it and  prevent creating the `yaml` file.